# issue with list in swift (Xcode 13.0)

Tags: swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var categories:[String:[Sticker]] {
        .init(
            grouping: stickerData, by: {$0.category.rawValue}
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            //Error in this line      
            List (categories.keys.sorted().identified(by: \String.self)){ key in
                StickerRow(categoryName: " Sticker \(key)".uppercased(), stickers: self.categories[key]!)
             }
        }          
    }
}
```

it display this error but I don't know what to do, any suggestions?

> Value of type '[Dictionary<String, [Sticker]>.Keys.Element]' (aka 'Array') has no member 'identified'

Sticker.swift code

```
    import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Sticker: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var imageName:String
    var category:Category
    var description:String
    
    enum Category: String, CaseIterable, Hashable, Codable {
    case first = "first"
    case second = "second"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It’s exactly as the error message says, an array doesn’t have a property named "identifier”, exactly what are you trying to do? What is it you want to loop over, the keys?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the code for `Sticker` as well.

Comment: I meant `identified(by:)` in my previous comment but I still don't understand the purpose of that call. And why do you need a dictionary, why not sort the `stickerData` array directly?

Comment: in answer at Joakim, thanks for the reorder of code.
I'm following a guide on YouTube for create an app, just to learn. but in this part of code I don't understand how to proceed. I'm posting the sticker.swift code

Comment: the object of this part of the video is to create the first screen of the app in the Homeview.swift.
you have to view what has been created in the various categories, in a single screen. for ex
FIRST CATEGORY
  (ScrollView) Element of the first category
SECOND CATEGORY
(ScrollView) Element of the second category

Comment: Ok, now I see what you want to do and why the dictionary is needed. Replace the faulty line with `List (categories.keys.sorted(), id: \.self)`

Comment: Much appreciate! in previous part I used this `(stickers, id: \.name) ` but honestly didn't try that in this part. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using identified, you can use id as below:

```
List(categories.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
     StickerRow(categoryName: " Sticker \(key)".uppercased(), stickers: self.categories[key]!)
```

}